# Using image overlay simultaneously with text in multicolumn mode beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a beamer slide where I have an image changing along with the text in the next column. For example:

```
\frame{\frametitle{testing cols}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{5cm} 
\begin{itemize}
\item On the next column you see a pic\pause
\item Pic is getting bigger! \pause
\item And it got even more big! 
\end{itemize}

\column[T]{10cm}
\includegraphics<1>[width=20mm]{pic.png}
\includegraphics<2>[width=30mm]{pic.png}
\includegraphics<3>[width=40mm]{pic.png}
\end{columns}
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing it completely wrong, but I want the image to change to the corresponding one each time text in the corresponding column changes. How can I get this to work?

---

After some attempt,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{testing cols}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{5cm} 
\begin{itemize}
\item On the next column you see a pic\pause
\item Pic is getting bigger! \pause
\item And it got even more big! 
\end{itemize}

\column[T]{10cm}
\includegraphics[width=20mm]{pic.png}\pause
\llap{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{pic.png}}\pause
\llap{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{pic.png}}
\end{columns}
}
end{document}
```

The image gets overlayed after the text cycle is complete. Can I make them simultaneous?

Comment: See page 85-86 in the manual for an example for this using with `\overprint` or `\llap`

Comment: @percusse Thanks. I used llap and now the pic is getting bigger but after the text overlay cycle is completed. How do I fix it? (Code in question)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the size issue. Martin H's example seems to solve the issue. Can you please include a full compilable MWE?

Comment: @percusse I included a MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution could be

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{testing cols}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.4\textwidth} 
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item On the next column you see a pic
\item Pic is getting bigger! 
\item And it got even more big! 
\end{itemize}
\column[T]{.6\textwidth}
\only<1>{\rule{100pt}{100pt}}
\only<2>{\rule{150pt}{150pt}}
\only<3>{\rule{200pt}{200pt}}
\end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

With the optinal `itemize` parameter `<+->` you can uncover the items one after another. I did not have you pictures so I had to work with `\only<>{}` and `\rule{x width}{y width}` you can just continue using `\includegraphics<1>...`.